# How to avoid Android Pie (call recordings BLOCKED!!!) with my security update?

Tags: updates, call-recording

My Huawei with Android 8 keeps pestering me constantly with "System Update Available for your device" and the choices are "download and install" and "later" but not "Leave me alone it's my damn phone". The update has a cryptic name like:

DRA-L21 1.0.0.151(C432)

Now, since **Android 9 has made it impossible to record calls any more** and that is the very most important feature in my phone, *how can I be sure that this or any other update is not going to install Android 9 but only security patches?*

Sources:

https://bitbucket.org/copluk/acr/issues/2418/kb-android-9-p-call-recording-issues

https://bgr.com/2018/08/15/android-pie-update-call-recording-apps-dead/

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-blocks-non-root-call-recording-apps/

https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/08/15/android-9-pie-puts-end-third-party-call-recording-apps/

Let me quote a paragraph from the first link, which explains the extent of the problem:

> A quick search on the Google Play Store shows more than 200 million total installs for over 200 call recording apps. It is clear that there is a legitimate need for call recording support. We alone received many thank you emails from our customers telling us **how call recording helped them to win legitimate court cases, recover financial losses, listen to voice of loved ones who are have passed away or even save their lives!**

Comment: Screw you, Google. Screw you in hell for this. What are the alternatives now?

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1. root the device and use a call recorder that uses root. 2. System apps should still be able to record calls. Therefore if Huawei would provide such an app it would work. You could try to start an online-petition at Huawei to sign one of the call recorder apps.